# what is equivalent to isEmpty() for integers?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, is-empty

Below is the script I have at the moment

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeeWhatTo 
{   
     public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //define scan  
       int a = scan.nextInt();
       int sum =0;
           while (a>0 )
     {                   
            sum = sum +a;
            a = scan.nextInt();    
     }
        System.out.println(sum);   //print out the sum
    }    
}
```

Currently,  it stores an input value in `a` and then adds it to `sum` and once a negative or zero is given as an input, it suspends itself and outputs the sum.

I was wondering if there's an integer equivalent of `isEmpty` so that i can do `while (! a.isEmpty() )`  so when there's no input but an enter, then it would stop and prints out the sum.

A natural followup from that would be, is there a way to assign an input integer to a and check if it is empty or not at the same time in the while condition as in `while ( ! (a=scan.nextInt()).isEmpty() )`

Comment: how about `scan.hasNextInt()`?

Comment: The default value of an int is 0. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Perdomoff you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent in the sense that you describe, since String is a variable-length collection of characters, and having zero characters is still a valid String.  One integer cannot contain zero integers, since by definition, it is already an integer.

However, your problem revolves around how Scanner works, rather than how int works.

Take a look at `scan.hasNextInt()`, which returns true if there is an int to read, and false otherwise.  This may give you what you want, using something like:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
while(scan.hasNextInt())
{
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    sum = sum + a;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: this was very helpful.  I have a question on how this works though.  i noticed that after it considers the very first input for the while condition, that input gets assigned to a, which i find curious...  Arent `scan.hasNextInt() ` and `scan.nextInt()` two independent scans?

Comment: also, if i just press enter without typing anything in, it keeps running, i guess it's because no input is regarded as `0` in java.. is there a way to get around this?

Comment: hasNextInt is a test that doesn't read or remove any characters, it just checks what is pending.  nextInt will actually remove the characters from the pending list and return the integer value of them.  The docs [hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) states that it only returns true if the next value is a valid int value, so if no input as a valid int value, is that an error in how it handles input?   hasNext() is apparently allowed to block while waiting for input, so I'll look.

Comment: ill accept your answer. if you end up finding an answer to this, let me know.  Thank you

Comment: `hasNextInt` buffers for the next token, so it does not do what the OP is asking. With `hasNextInt`, you can type `a` or `b` or something like that to break out of the loop (any token that's not able to be parsed to `int`), but it will prompt forever and ignore whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner` can do 2 things:

- Read line-by-line (`nextLine`).
- Read token-by-token (`next` or e.g. `nextInt`).

These are really two different functionalities of `Scanner`, and if you're reading tokens then your `Scanner` basically doesn't know about empty lines.

If you call `nextInt`, `Scanner` does two things:

- Finds the next token (default: delimited by *any* whitespace).
- Tries to turn it in to an `int`.

The tokenizing behavior is an important feature of `Scanner`. If you enter `1 2\n` and call `nextInt` twice, you get `1` and `2`. However, if you enter an empty line, the tokenizing `Scanner` just skips it as whitespace and keeps looking for another token.

So the straightforward answer is "no": you can never get an "empty" `int` from a call to `nextInt` in a simply way and still retain the token-by-token behavior. (That's beyond the fact that a primitive variable in Java can't be "empty".)

One easy way to do what you're asking is to use line-by-line reading instead and call `parseInt` yourself:

```
Scanner systemIn = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;

String line;
while (!(line = systemIn.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(line);
}
```

But you lose the tokenizing behavior. Now, if you enter `1 2\n`, an exception is thrown because `nextLine` finds `1 2`.

You can still read token-by-token with `nextInt`, but it's more complicated, using a second `Scanner`:

```
Scanner systemIn = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;

String nextLine;
while (!(nextLine = systemIn.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    Scanner theInts = new Scanner(nextLine);

    while (theInts.hasNextInt()) {
        sum += theInts.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Here, we can enter `1 2\n`, get `1 2` as our next line, then ask the second `Scanner` to tokenize it.

So yes, you can program the functionality you're looking for, but not in an easy way, because `Scanner` is more complicated.

*edit*

Possibly another way is to use a delimiter on the line separator:

```
// use System.getProperty("line.separator") in 1.6
Scanner systemIn = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
int sum = 0;

while (systemIn.hasNextInt()) {
    sum += systemIn.nextInt();
}
```

Now, `nextInt` tokenizes the same way as `nextLine`. This will break the loop for any input that's not an `int`, including empty tokens. (Empty tokens aren't possible with the default delimiter.) I'm never really sure if people actually expect `Scanner`'s default delimiting to work the way it does or not. It's possible creating a `Scanner` in this way makes it behave closer to what people seem to expect for reading the console, just line-by-line.

Comment: You still need to call `hasNextLine()` rather than just test for line being empty. `nextLine()` will throw an exception if there is no next line to read (e.g. if you press CTRL/Z or CTRL/D to signify end-of-file).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou There are also other things we should do, like catch `InputMismatchException`/`NumberFormatException`, but I usually forego this sort of thing for example code.

Comment: Since you're calling `hasNextInt` before calling `nextInt`, it won't throw an `InputMismatchException` or `NumberFormatException`. But you really should call `hasNextLine` since it is a real possibility that there will not be a next line: not only by pressing EOF (which the user may quite possibly do to indicate there's nothing left to input) but also if the user redirects standard input (again a real possibility and quite a normal way to run a program).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You aren't wrong, I'm just explaining why it's not in my post. It's irrelevant to the matter of the question and makes the code a little more difficult to follow.